# Spring Kafka bean return types

Tags: spring-kafka

The documentation for spring kafka stream support shows something like:

```
@Bean
public KStream<Integer, String> kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
    KStream<Integer, String> stream = kStreamBuilder.stream("streamingTopic1");
// ... stream config
    return stream;
}
```

However, I might want a topology dependent on multiple streams or tables. Can I do:

```
@Bean
public KStream<Integer, String> kStream(StreamsBuilder kStreamBuilder) {
    KStream<Integer, String> stream1 = kStreamBuilder.stream("streamingTopic1");
    KStream<Integer, String> stream2 = kStreamBuilder.stream("streamingTopic1");
// ... stream config
    return stream;
}
```

In other words, is the bean returned relevant, or is it only important that kStreamBuilder is being mutated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

If you don't need a reference to the `KStream` elsewhere, there is no need to define it as a bean at all you can auto wire the `StreamsBuilder` which is created by the factory bean.

If you need a reference, then each one must be its own bean.

For example, Spring Cloud Stream builds a partial stream which the application then modifies. [See here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder).

Comment: So, to be clear, I `@Autowired` StreamBuilder it into another `@Configuration`  than the one that defines the KafkaStreamsConfiguration (have to, or its circular), then set the bean in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.  That seems to work.  Thanks.  (Also, just using a `@Bean` seems to work, too.)

Comment: Yes; as I said, it only needs to be a `@Bean` if you need to reference it elsewhere.